# High Performance `try...catch` (alternative?)

Tags: c#, performance, loops, try-catch, gdi+

*This may sound like a weird question, but*
I have written a sort of graphic calculator using GDI+ in C#. I am rather happy with the result and its "usual" performance.

The only problem is, that if the function is not fully defined¹⁾, the rendering method will have huge performance issues, which is due to a `try..catch`-block inside my rendering loop:

```
private void draw(....,Graphics g)
{
    // this is e.g. the function ƒ(x) := x⁻¹
    Func<double, double> mathematical_method = .....;

    ...

    // The variables `left` and `right` are the visible pixels translated
    // into function coordinates, so that we only draw the pixels we really need
    for (double x = left; x < right; x += step)
        try
        {
            // Draws the lines of the graph at their respected points
            g.Draw( ......  x, mathematical_method(x));
        }
        catch
        {
            // in case of a non-definition
            g.Draw( ..whatever.. )
        }

    ...
}
```

As you might have guessed - this is not the best solution, so I am wondering, whether it is possible to make this `try..catch`-block more performant *(e.g. by somehow disabling the CLR's method which is responsible for stack trace collection etc.)* or how I could otherwise solve this issue....

---

**EDIT №1:** I forgot to mention, that the user can enter any mathematical expression into the calculator (without having to give the complete definition set of the expression) - so a `if...else` is not really an option...

*Random thoughts of mine: I could somehow implement a `function cache` which uses `try..catch` in the first drawing iteration and then 'learns', where the function f is not defined.*

---

1) With "not fully defined" I mean e.g. the function `ƒ : ℝ\{0}⟶ℝ : x⟼x⁻¹` which is not defined for the x-value `0`

Comment: Can the success/fail of the draw be known before hand? If it does, consider using `if-else` statement, it would boost up your speed significantly

Comment: Exception handlers are for catching unpredictable exceptions - it sounds like a non-definition shouldn't be exceptional in your case, and it's something you should be checking for with an `if`.

Comment: What's providing `mathematical_method`? (Now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions, btw...)

Comment: @Ian, @James Thorpe: I have updated my question:
@Jon Skeet: In reality, it is a class written by myself, which is based upon the `Func<double, double>`-delegate.

Comment: I'm surprised. `try/catch` is somewhat expensive, but it should be negligible when compared to `Draw`. Have you tried to launch your code in release mode without attaching the debugger? Does the performance issue persists?

Comment: @KooKiz: damn - you are quite right, Sir. The performance gain is massive without the debugger.... I have not tested it before in release configuration as I thought that I could optimize my code further before launching the application without VS attached....

Comment: The problem is that your function seems to be throwing exceptions for "undefined" cases. A better alternative would be to define it as `Func<double, double?>` and return `null` is such cases, so the drawing code can use the result w/o `try/catch`.